# Warning: Cannot update a component (`SearchingNameProvider`) while rendering a different component (`Searching`) React Context

Tags: reactjs, context

1. Tengo un componente Results que hace un fetch a la api de pokemon envía en el componente Card el resultado del fetch en la prop pokemons
2. En el componente Card recibo la información y hago otro fetch con el nombre del pokemon, este componente muestra la imagen y el nombre del Pokémon
   Ahora al hacer click sobre sobre las imagenes de la izquierda, quiero mostrar los detalles de ese
   pokemon en el lado derecho, para eso hice un contexto
3. En la carpeta contexts/searchingNameContext
   Cuando le doy click en Card.js a cada pokemon actualiza el estado mediante las funciones actualizadoras que estan en el cotext
4. Tengo un componente llamado Searching.js y quiero introducir el nombre de un pokemon y mostralo en la parte derecha
   para eso quiero actualizar el estado global con las mismas funciones
5. Ahora cuando cargo la pagina, hago click sobre algun pokemon se muestar al lado derecho los detalles de ese pokemon, ahora escribo el nombre de
   de un pokemon en el imput y efectivamente muestra el detalle del pokemon que escribí.

pero si vuelvo a hacer click en alguno de los elementos del lado izquierdo ya no funciona y muestra

index.js:1 Warning: Cannot update a component (`SearchingNameProvider`) while rendering a different component (`Searching`). To locate the bad setState() call inside  `Searching`
Adjunto el repositorio por si desean echarle un ojo

===> https://github.com/jhonfe64/api.git

Gracias por la ayuda

```
//componente Searching

import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {SearchingNameContext} from '../contexts/SearchingNameContext';


const Searching = () => {
    
    //lo que hay que hacer es actualizar los estados globales
    let {searchingName, changeSearchingName} = useContext(SearchingNameContext);
    let {pokemonType, changePokemonType} = useContext(SearchingNameContext);
    let {pokemonId, changePokemonId} = useContext(SearchingNameContext);
    let {pokemonImage, changePokemonImage} = useContext(SearchingNameContext);
    let {pokemonAbilities, changePokemonHabilities} = useContext(SearchingNameContext);

    const [btnClick, setBtnClick] = useState(false);
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
    const [fullInputvalue, setFullInputValue] = useState('');
    const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState();

    const handleInputValue = (e) => {
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        setBtnClick(true);
        e.preventDefault();
        setFullInputValue(inputValue);
    }
  
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(btnClick === true){
            fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${fullInputvalue}`)
        .then((res)=>{
            return res.json();
        }).then((singlePokemon)=>{
            setPokemon(singlePokemon);
        })
        }
    },[btnClick, inputValue, fullInputvalue]);
 

    return (
        <div>
            <SearchingPokemons>
                {
                    btnClick === true && pokemon ?(
                        changeSearchingName(pokemon.name),
                        changePokemonType(pokemon.types[0].type.name),
                        changePokemonId(pokemon.id),
                        changePokemonImage(pokemon.sprites.front_default),
                        changePokemonHabilities(pokemon.abilities)
                    )
                    
                     : ""
                }
                
                <PokemonInput onChange={handleInputValue} value={inputValue} placeholder="Search" type="text"/>
                <PokemonBtn onClick={handleClick}>Search</PokemonBtn>
            </SearchingPokemons>
        </div>
    );
}


const SearchingPokemons = styled.form`
    display: flex;
`
const PokemonInput = styled.input`
    width: 95%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    border: 2px solid #ecf0f1;
    border-right: none;
    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
`

const PokemonBtn = styled.button`
    background: red;
    border: none;
    width: 15%;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
`



export default Searching;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que no se puede actualizar el estado de contexto en `render time`  (dentro del return), el problema parece estar en la lógica del operador ternario dentro de `<SearchingPokemons>`, ahi dentro se esta tratando de cambiar el estado en render time (dentro del return), yo intentaría hacer esa lógica fuera del `return`, de alguna forma.

Comment: De acuerdo con @g.4, no veo que el operador ternario renderize JSX, podrías intentar un useEffect fuera del return

Answer (score 0):

El problema se puede deber a que se estan llamando funciones setter en render time(dentro del `return`), las funciones de este tipo, van usualmente dentro de una funcion `handler`, fuera del `return`.

Se puede llamar a estas funciones y hacer el cambio de las variables de contexto, en el primer `useEffect` (donde se hace `fecth`), descartando el estado `pokemon`(no es necesario):

```
useEffect(()=>{
        if(btnClick === true){
            fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${fullInputvalue}`)
        .then((res)=>{
            return res.json();
        }).then((singlePokemon)=>{
            console.log("in fetch")
            //setPokemon(singlePokemon);
            changeSearchingName(singlePokemon.name)
            changePokemonType(singlePokemon.types[0].type.name)
            changePokemonId(singlePokemon.id)
            changePokemonImage(singlePokemon.sprites.front_default)
            changePokemonHabilities(singlePokemon.abilities)
        })
        }
    },[btnClick, inputValue, fullInputvalue]);
```

Hay que eliminar esta pieza de código para que lo anterior funcione:

```
 <SearchingPokemons>
                {/* eliminar esto
                    btnClick === true && pokemon ?(
                        changeSearchingName(pokemon.name),
                        changePokemonType(pokemon.types[0].type.name),
                        changePokemonId(pokemon.id),
                        changePokemonImage(pokemon.sprites.front_default),
                        changePokemonHabilities(pokemon.abilities)
                    )
                    
                     : ""
                    */ }
                
                ...
            </SearchingPokemons>
```

Ahora, el `useEffect` se va a quejar por que faltan dependencias (todas las funciones setter de `SearchingNameContext`), lo que yo haría es crear una sola función que haga la actualización de todas esas variables en  `SearchingNameContext`, para solo listar una función setter en las depenencias de `useEffect`.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.